# Creating a sprite class in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I am working on making a sprite class in OpenGL ES 2.0 and have succeeded to a point. Currently I have a render method for the sprite and it's called by the render method in my EAGL layer at intervals. I was creating new vertex buffer and index buffer every time render was called but it isn't efficient so I called glremovebuffer. Unfortunately when I do that the frame-rate is slowed down significantly.

So currently I have the vbo and ibo created at initialization which works fine in terms of frame-rate and memory consumption but is unable to update position.

I'm at a bit of a loss as I'm just beggining with OpenGL, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you want to create your sprite with VBOs and IBOs once, located at the model origin. To translate, rotate, and scale, you would then use the model matrix to transform your sprite into a desired location.

I'm fairly certain that iphone sdk provides some nice functions to do that, but I don't know any of them :) Basically, in your shader, you take your position coordinates and you multiply it by one or more matrices, one of those matrices is the model matrix, which you can change to be a translate, rotate, scale, or any combination of those matrices (in fact, it can be any matrix you want and it will produce different results).

There's a lot of resources out there that explain these transformation matrices. Here's one for instance:
http://db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/

My advise is to find a tutorial that speaks on the same level as your understand and learn from there...